# How to pass methods with parameters to children in React? (Cannot read property 'props' of undefined)

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently making a to-do list, but unfortunately ran into some errors where I am unable to pass methods to a child component.

```
const React = require('react');
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      input: ""
    }
    this.inputChange = this.inputChange.bind(this);
    this.addItems = this.addItems.bind(this);
    this.remItems = this.remItems.bind(this);   
  }
  inputChange(event){
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value
    })
  }

  addItems(){
    event.preventDefault()
    const temp = this.state.input 
    this.setState({
      input: "",
      items: this.state.items.concat(temp)
    })
  }
  remItems(id){
    const temp = [...this.state.items]
    const updatedItems = temp.filter(item => item.id!==id)
    this.setState({
      items: updatedItems
    })
  }
  render(){
  return (
    <div class = "w-100 p-3">
        <p>Enter your item here:</p>
       <form onSubmit = {this.addItems} class="form.inline">  
          <input class = "form.control mb-2 mr-sm-2" value = {this.state.input} onChange = {this.inputChange}/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Add</button>
      </form>
      <UnorderedList items={this.state.items} remove = {this.remItems}/>
    </div>
  );
  }
}

class UnorderedList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render(){
  return (
    <ul>
      {this.props.items.map(function(item, i) {
        return (<div id = "entry" class = "d-flex">
            <li key={i}>{item}</li>
            {console.log(i)}
            <button class = 'btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-auto' onClick = {() => this.remItems}> Done! </button>
          </div>)
      })}
    </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

I expected to be able to remove the items by id key but it gives me "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined". Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have to bind remItems to your component instance. Either by declaring it as an arrow function `remItems = (id) => {...}` or by explicitely binding it in the constructor `this.remItems = this.remItems.bind(this)`

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem. It's unknown where you have this error. Once you have `this.remItems = this.remItems.bind(this)`, the error shouldn't occur in remItems.

Comment: I've edited the code, sorry!

Comment: @snao good you added the code. but can you take a look here
```<button class = 'btn btn-sm btn-primary ml-auto' onClick = {() => this.remItems}> Done! </button>```. 'onClick' should be ```onClick={()=> this.remItems(item.id)}```

Comment: Solved, sorry! In remItems(id), my item doesn't actually have a id property.. My bad.